# Fullcalendar and Vuex

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, state, vuex

After fullcalendar updated their props to go outside of the `<FullCalendar />` element I have some problems rendering events.
I know that the state request is fulfilled in Vuex because I've tested this so many this without a getter and with a getter and nothing seems to work...

```
<template>
<v-container>
            <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" />

            <li v-for="event in events" :key="event.id"> 
                {{event.name + ' ' + event.start}}
            </li>
</v-container>
</template>

<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'

import { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'


export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ,dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        selectable: true,
        events: this.allEvents,
      }
    }
  },
   computed: {
        ...mapState({
            events: state => state.calendar.events
        }),
        ...mapGetters('calendar', ['allEvents']),
    },
    created () {
      this.getAll();
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('calendar', {
            getAll: 'getAll',
        }),
    }
}
</script>
```

Is there any way to render the elements with just the state? I thought that setting events to this.events would be working, but I'm probably way off here. I'm new to Vue and Vuex so help is much appreciated! :) The list is just to know that the state is working as it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still bind the events in template by doing something like this:

```html
    <FullCalendar :options="{
      ...calendarOptions,
      events: events
    }" />
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't find that in the docs, probably will have to get some glasses.. Do you know why it works by binding it in the template but not in the calendarOptions? And would it be more suitable to use a getter or just to map the state? Would this also go for binding @ attributes?

Comment: Its the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax, it allows you to extend your object, arrays or strings. The data prop is evaluated before your computed props, so your computed prop is not set yet. You can see the getter as a computed property in your store, if you want to do something with the state you use a getter, if you don't you can use the state.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and in depth explanation that I needed! Much appreciated man!